# Не понимаю как работает код с конструктором копирования и оператором присваивания

Tags: c++, ооп

```
class string {
private:
    char* str;
    int length;
public:
    string() {
        str = nullptr;
        length = 0;
    }
    string(const char* str) {
        length = strlen(str);
        this->str = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            this->str[i] = str[i];
        }
        this->str[length] = '\0';
    }
    ~string() {
        delete[] this->str;
    }
    
     string(const string& other) {
        length = strlen(other.str);

        this->str = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        }
        this->str[length] = '\0';
    }
    
    
    string operator + (const string& other) {
        string result;
        result.length = length + other.length;
        result.str = new char[result.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result.str[i] = this->str[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < other.length; i++) {
            result.str[length+i] = other.str[i];
        }
        result.str[result.length] = '\0';
        return result;
    }
    string& operator = (const string& other) {
        length = strlen(other.str);
        if (this->str != nullptr) {
            delete[] this->str;
        }
        this->str = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        }
        this->str[length] = '\0';
        return *this;
    }
    string& operator = (const char* str) {
        length = strlen(str);
        if (this->str != nullptr) {
            delete[] this->str;
        }
        this->str = new char[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            this->str[i] = str[i];
        }
        this->str[length] = '\0';
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator ==(const string& other) {
        if (length != other.length) return false;
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (this->str[i] != other.str[i]) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool operator !=(const string& other) {
        return !(this->operator==(other));
    }

    char& operator [](unsigned int index) {
        return this->str[index];
    }

    void Print() {
        if (this->str) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(this->str); i++) {
                cout << this->str[i];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    int Length() {
        return length;
    }
```

};

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    string a = "Первый";
    string b = "Второй";


    string result = a + b;
    result.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Я предполагал, что конструктор копирования используется для инициализации объекта при его создании. Но тут я потыкал в отладчике и он не заходит ни в конструктор копирования, ни в перегруженный оператор присваивания. Даже закомментировав конструктор и оператор код по прежнему работает. Не понимаю как в result оказывается результат конкатенации строк.

Comment: вы в `string operator + (const string& other)` возвращаете временный объект. А в свежих версиях Си++ стандарта код `string result = a + b;` запрещает использовать бессмысленную копию возвращаемого значения. И тогда вызова конструктора копирования не происходит вообще. *Эта операция будет аналогична такой :* `string && result = a + b;`

Comment: .. и `result` будет ссылкой на возвращаемый временный объект. Конструктора копирования не будет и время жизни временного объекта будет увеличено до времени жизни ссылки `result &&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В С++17 гарантируется, что компилятор будет убирать некоторые избыточные копии объекта. Это называется "[mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)" или "mandatory RVO" (в более старых версиях это было на усмотрение компилятора).

Это происходит, когда 1+ временных объектов (prvalue) перемещаются (в вашем случае - то же самое что копируются; читайте про move-семантику) один в другой. Тогда они они все, и плюс крайний не-prvalue объект, в который записался результат, магическим образом объединяются в один объект. У них даже адрес становится одинаковый. Это все происходит во время компиляции, и никак не замедляет программу. По сути, объект просто сразу конструируется по нужному адресу.

Давайте считать перемещения:

- `string result;` -> `return result;` - `result` перемещается во временный объект. Здесь исходный объект не prvalue, а xvalue (заметьте, не lvalue, `return` в таких ситуациях по сути делает автоматический `move()`), поэтому mandatory copy elision не применяется. На усмотрение компилятора здесь происходит NRVO (та же самая оптимизация, но не гарантируемая стандартом). Тут любой нормальный компилятор ее успешно сделает.
- `string result = a + b;` - здесь тот же самый временный объект, который создал `return`, перемещается в `result`. Здесь исходный объект - prvalue, а result - нет. Тут срабатывает mandatory RVO. (Вообще, если [вчитаться](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.6.3), инициализация с `=` сначала создает еще один временный объект, а потом перемещает его в создаваемую переменную, так что RVO срабатывает два раза, а не один. Но это больше формальность, нормальный компилятор и до C++17 выкинул бы лишний временный объект.)

В итоге, `string result;` внутри функции и `string result` в мейне считаются одним и тем же объектом, и копирования/перемещения не происходит.

---

Пара замечаний:

- `operator = (const char* str)` - лишний, достаточно конструктора с параметром `const char *str`.
- `const` забыт на `operator+`, `operator==`, `operator!=`, `Print()`, `Length()`.
- В С++20 можно убрать `operator!=`, он получается автоматически если есть `operator==`.
- В `operator = (const string& other)`:

  - Забыта проверка на `this != &other`
  - Все сломается, если `new` выбросит исключение. По идее, надо сначала звать `new`, сохранять во временную переменную результат, и если он успешно позвался, уже тогда делать `delete`.
  - И то и другое можно починить не думая, если переписать используя copy&swap idiom:

    ```
    string &operator=(string other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(str, other.str);
        std::swap(length, other.length);
        return *this;
    }
    ```

    Это позволяет в 99% случаев писать `operator=` не думая.
- Забыта константная перегрузка `operator[]`. Например так:

  ```
        char &operator[](unsigned int index)       {return this->str[index];}
  const char &operator[](unsigned int index) const {return this->str[index];}
  ```

  Ну и вообще, у вас как-то странно сделано - где-то `int`, где-то `unsigned int`.

  Лучше везде что-то одно, например `std::size_t` или `std::ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Спасибо! Большинство из ваших слов я не понял, так как только начинаю изучать и вижу это в первый раз. Но вы дали мне пищу для размышлений и изучения, за что вам огромное спасибо! И всё-таки, получается, что сам компилятор совершает это действие с переносом? А если я определю конструктор переноса, будет использоваться он?

Comment: @Shuazo Если какие-то слова непонятны, говорите какие, попробую объяснить. Нет, от добавления перемещающего конструктора ничего не поменяется. (Вообще, если вы написали копирующий конструктор, а перемещающий не написали, то перемещающий перестает генерироваться компилятором автоматически, и при попытке переместить зовется копирующий.)

Comment: Спустя время я понял первый абзац. Но я не до конца осознаю категории  value, так как во всем прочитанном мною они разделяются на те, что перемещаются/не перемещаются и (не)обладающие идентичностью, но конкретных примеров я не нашел, а из этих определений не сильно что понял. 
1ое перемещение: не совсем понимаю почему xvalue(немного осознал почему не rvalue). Из-за того что result это объект функции по итогу окончания которой у нас останется только его значение, которое и вернется? И в случае с xvalue rvo не происходит, потому что это не prvalue. А nrvo происходит только с xvalue?

Comment: И перемещения происходят так: 1) Из фукнции ретерном на момент вызова (a+b) и потом 2)уже в саму переменную result. То есть RVO и NRVO это то, что происходит для самой операции перемещения?2ое перемещение вроде понял, result тут lvalue.
По поводу замечаний: Я слышал про правило трех, поэтому так тут и сделал. И я не понял, его достаточно в целях данной программы или в принципе для этого класса?

Comment: Попробовал убрать оператор != не скомпилировал( Про  исключения еще ничего не знаю... В константной перегрузке это разве не что-то вроде константной функции? Они же работают только с константными классами. Огромное спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: @Shuazo *"не до конца осознаю категории value"* Так, поехали. :) Эти категории есть у выражений, не у объектов. Выражение - это кусочек кода, который обозначает объект. (Несколько разных выражений могут обозначать один и тот же обзект, но иметь разные категории, например `x` и `std::mvove(x)`.) "prvalue" - это выражение, которое само только что создало объект, например `std::string(42)`, или вызов любой функции, возвращающей по значению. "xvalue" - это выражение, обозначающее объект, который скоро будет уничтожен, ...

Comment: @Shuazo ...но при этом создало его не оно само - например результат вызова любой функции, возвращающей `&&`-ссылку. Ну и "lvalue" обозначает объект, который это выражение не создавало, и который в ближайшее время не собирается умирать. Все эти объяснения про *"обладающие идентичностью"* мне кажутся довольно туманными.

Comment: *"1ое перемещение: не совсем понимаю почему xvalue(немного осознал почему не rvalue)"* Rvalue - это либо prvalue, либо xvalue, поэтому осознали неправильно. Обычно `result` был бы lvalue, но есть особое правило, что когда функция возвращает локальную переменную по значению, эта переменная автоматически считается xvalue вместо lvalue (то есть как будто бы компилятор сам делает `std::move`, с той разницей, что если написать `std::move` руками, то компилятор больше не сможет сделать NRVO, поэтому лучше его не писать).

Comment: На счет примеров выражений разных категорий - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: *"А nrvo происходит только с xvalue?"* Нет, там более узкое правило. Компилятор имеет правило сделать NRVO, если функция возвращает по значению, есть локальная переменная такого же типа, и программист ее и возвращает. А если, например, сделать `return std::move(эта_же_переменная);`, то NRVO больше не разрешен, хотя, казалось бы, и там и там xvalue. Вот тут должны быть подробнсти: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: *"То есть RVO и NRVO это то, что происходит для самой операции перемещения?"* (N)RVO заменяет перемещение. Компилятор волшебным образом делает так, что исходный и целевой объект становятся одним и тем же объектом, поэтому и перемещать теперь ничего не нужно, объект сразу конструируется по нужному адресу. (Под капотом в вашем примеру, как я понимаю, адрес куска памяти на стеке `main`а передается в `operator+`, а тот вызывает для этого куска конструтор и дальше что-то с ним делает.)

Comment: *"2ое перемещение вроде понял, result тут lvalue"* Угу, хотя не так важно, что это lvalue. Разве что в том смысле, что не prvalue, поэтому цепочка применений RVO заканчивается на этом объекте, и результат попадает в него.

Comment: *"Я слышал про правило трех, поэтому так тут и сделал."* Хмм, так я вроде и не советовал не соблюдать. Или вы про copy&swap idiom? Такой `operator=` подходит под правило, тут главное что его не компилятор генерировал. *"И я не понял, его достаточно в целях данной программы или в принципе для этого класса?"* Достаточно в том смысле, что память течь не будет, и класс будет корректно управлять памятью. Но лучше дописать еще перемещающий конструктор и оператор присваивания, тогда в некоторых случаях будет работать быстрее. Хотя конкретно в вашей примере из-за RVO они в итоге не вызываются.

Comment: @Shuazo *"Попробовал убрать оператор != не скомпилировал"* Значит компилятор старый, или вы не включили в настройках C++20. Если скажете, что за компилятор (название и версия, если на винде - еще и ссылка, откуда качали), подскажу где включать. *"Про исключения еще ничего не знаю..."* Вас ждут непрятные сюрпризы. >:D *"не что-то вроде константной функции? Они же работают только с константными классами"* Нет, они работают с любыми. Наборот, неконстантные функции работают только с неконстантными объектами.

Comment: В паре мест опечатался, но смысл должен быть понятен. В интересном порядке изучаете, конечно. :) const-функции - это базовая вещь, а категории выражений по памяти большинство программистов так себе знает.

Comment: Ага, благодаря вашим объяснениям и куче информации на иных сайтах я наконец понял, что происходило в коде, а так же value категории. На последний вопрос, что терзает меня : по сути RVO/NRVO работает только при инициализации нового объекта?

Comment: @Shuazo Поздравляю! :) Да.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо вам огромное за помощь в этом вопросе! Без вас бы ничего не получилось!